# CDS Time zone independent Date Time fields not available in Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, common-data-service

I'm creating some PowerApps to extend D365 Talent functionality.

For some reason, none of the Date and Time fields with Behaviour 'Time zone independent' are available in Powerapps...

Here's an example of a custom entity with 2 Date and Time fields. One is User Local, and appears in the list of fields in Power Apps, the other is Time zone independent and isn't visible.

Here's some images that show one example of this behaviour:

**Entity Fields list**
[image: Entity Fields list]

**Time zone independent Field**
[image: Time zone independent Field]

**User Local Field**
[image: User Local Field]

**List of Fields in PowerApps**
[image: List of Fields in PowerApps]

I have logic in my PowerApp that is dependent on these values. Does anyone know a workaround, or fix?

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks RussellB - I did read this. Given the nature of the problem, I thought images showing exactly what was happening was much more clear than a textual description of the example.

Comment: Any follow up questions? Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You’re right. It was hidden by design due to some limitations & fixed later (May 2019).

> Canvas apps now fully support CDS time zone independent fields.  In the CDS preview connector we had blocked them until they were working properly.  All the work required has now been completed and fully deployed.

[Reference](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/time-zone-independent-fields-for-canvas-apps/)